# Xcode compiler show errors in 100% right codes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

After i updated my Xcode to 6.0 i have this strange errors that is not should appear because the code is 100% true and i updated to 6.1 but still the same problem i deleted the Xcode and reinstall it 3 times but nothing happened.

most of the error is in Objective-C codes because i didn’t use swift until now so I’m not sure about swift codes.

**and after i updated to 6.0 most of the time i run the app in the IOS Simulator the Xcode project force close i need to re open the project and run it 2-5 times until it work and simulate it**

*at least is there a way to debug the app even if there errors*

Samples :

[sample pic1](http://gyazo.com/a1d155159d6c0d2bbe3bab2be316b16f)

[sample pic2](http://gyazo.com/6917ca0810383ffdb760be17be7965a2)

Comment: Cleaning the build folder often helps me when I get aberrant compilation errors after doing an Xcode update.

Comment: That's clearly not the case here :) The OP has a syntax error.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to look closely to spot those silly mistakes than reinstalling ;)

Comment: @sha - Ahh! I couldn't load screenshots to see, blocked by work. :(

Answer (score 2):

You have a colon after `Deleted` property. It should be semicolon.